# "Try me": Too Sexually Suggestive and "Slangy" for Retail Marketing?

Tags: expressions, slang, business-language, appropriate

Is the expression “Try Me” inappropriately sexually suggestive and “slangy” for use in retail marketing?

A client wants an expression for use on a sticker for an electronic device in a retail store to invite customers to try out the device. “Try me” was suggested as common and effective. However, others have warned that “Try me” is inappropriate as likely to be considered lewd.

Which view is correct? And if “Try me” is inappropriate or if the client insists on another expression, what would be more appropriate?

Comment: Anyone who thinks 'Try me' on an electronic device might be considered lewd needs to seek professional advice for some other deep seated issue. If it was on a t-shirt aimed at young girls then I could see the point but for an electronic device - no, not at all lewd.

Comment: As long as it's not an electric chair.

Comment: You could always use "Try it", or you could go the other way and have a picture of a Victoria's Secret model on the sticker. I don't see any issue with "Try me".

Answer (score 1):

Not at all -I've seen the text on directional stickers to indicate where to press the button and an alternative use is "press me"

Answer (score 1):

Years ago, National Airlines generated a lot of flack when they ran their *Fly me* ad campaign. Now there's an airline actually named FLYme.

I don't think *Try me* on the back of a device is at all suggestive, and I've been called prudish (of course, that's not exactly true...). I also don't think it's at all too slangy.

All the synonyms for try me are either too stodgy or much worse re. innuendo.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is appropriate. The sexual misunderstanding you are referring to can actually be a *marketing tool* to attract customers' attention. But I don't think it  is unsuitable.